# Apache won't bind to ANY port (OS 10048)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, wamp, windows-server-2008-r2

I can't get the Apache service to start.

When I try to start it from services I get the following events in event viewer.

- > > > The Apache service named  reported the following error: (OS
  > > >       10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network
  > > >       address/port) is normally permitted.  : AH00072: make_sock: could not
  > > >       bind to address 0.0.0.0:8090

  - > > > AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down  .
  - > > > AH00015: Unable to open logs

  .

I've tried port 80 port 8080 and 8090 and I'm getting the same errors.
I've checked to see if these ports are in use and they are not listed through netstat or through a currports.exe I've used.

I had everything running but I did a SYMLINKS rebuild on apache and mysql and I think I may have done them too quick as I got an error message at the time and mysql and apache stayed down.
I had to re-install the mysql service but the Apache service is going nowhere!!

I have wamp 2.5 with apache 2.4.9 running on windows 2008 R2 Enterprise for the purpose of an office intranet using wordpress.

Help very much appreciated

Cheers

JCro

```
EDIT Code from Httd.conf. I have just added the lines I've amended                   #
#
Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen 80
#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
# 

#
ServerName localhost:80
HostnameLookups Off

#
```

Comment: ..and Skype, and put it back on port 80.

Comment: HI Adelphina, thanks for your reply. I've done that and I'm still having the same issue. There's no skype running on the server and I've checked for anything else using it and there isn't

Comment: How did you do _a SYMLINKS rebuild_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not too clear what caused this situation but this may get you back up and running.

Start WAMPServer

uninstall the Apache service

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Remove Service
```

reinstall the Apache service

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install Service
```

start Apache

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Start/Resume Service
```

Now if you ever want to rebuild the Apache SYMLINKS (mysql has non by default) you do this :-

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> (click on the current version number)
```

Then wait a few seconds while WAMPServer rebuilds the SYMLINKS and restarts Apache for you.

Oh then I would put Apache back to Listen on port 80.

***RE: Your `httpd.conf` amendments***

This line should be a comment, its an example but not intended to be part of the used parameters in this file

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
```

These 2 lines shoud be

```
# this is for IPV4
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
# This is for IPV6
Listen [::0]:80
```

These 2 lines look ok as

```
ServerName localhost:80
HostnameLookups Off
```

Comment: RiggFolly - Thanks, I've tried this a couple of times also but she's still not starting. I've tried again as per your instructions but still no joy. I did the SYMLINKS rebuild as you have in your instructions. But I did the mysql SYMLINKS pretty much at the same time and I think I had some error at the time - that seemed to cause all this hassle. Could this have created some kind of conflict??

Comment: Unless you have done some mods. MYSQL does not have any SYMLINKS! At least not in vanilla WAMPServer

Comment: Have you done any changes to `httpd.conf` or `my.ini` apart from the Listen port change in `httpd.conf`

Comment: I've been amending http.conf to make the port changes. I'll attach the lines I've been amending below; >#
>#
>Listen 12.34.56.78:80
>Listen 0.0.0.0:80
>Listen 80
>#                                                                                                                                
># Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
>#                                                                                                                          ># If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP >address here.
>#
>ServerName localhost:80
>HostnameLookups Off
>
>#

Comment: Apologies was not able to amend the last comment before 5 minutes elapsed. Ill add the http.conf code to the main question

Comment: See the answer for info on you `httpd.conf` changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90542/discussion-between-user2083702-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: This has resolved my issue. Had taken what i thought was a default httd.conf from google while troubleshooting. Gracias and Cheers to all

Answer (score 1):

How to see port number in Windows 10?

```
Open a command prompt window (as Administrator) From "Start\Search box" Enter "cmd" then right-click on "cmd.exe" and select "Run as Administrator"
Enter the following text then hit Enter. netstat -abno. ...
Find the Port that you are listening on under "Local Address"
Look at the process name directly under that.
```

After you found the PID of the service running on a given your computer, open your task Manager and sort the running processes by PID. find your target PID right click and go to services, right click on the service and stop the service. without starting your apache 2.4 service just start by getting this path "C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -k start" then enter. This is the way I become successful after many ups and down.

Answer (score 0):

OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80 (OS 10048)Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. : AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down AH00015: Unable to open logs

I was getting the same error when i tried to start the Apache2.4. But when i replaced the Listen 80 with Listen 8080(by going to httpd.conf file placed in conf folder inside Apache24 folder), my problem solved.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

you may still get the complaint about port 443. If you look through the httpd.conf,  you won’t be able to find 443. But, you will find the following:

## Secure (SSL/TLS) connections

Include “conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf”

Look in the httpd-ssl.conf file, and replace 443 with some other port.

Enjoy!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).